# Hibernate cannot persist object due to "Request method 'POST' not supported"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm having the follow problem:

This is my form code:

```
<form:form class="form-material validate-form" modelAttribute="Usuario_form" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/FormActionUser" method="POST" id="userForm">
```

This is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/FormActionUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "Crear")
  public ModelAndView CrearUsuario(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
  @ModelAttribute("Usuario_form") Usuario usuario_form) {
    System.out.println("*****" + request.getMethod() + "*****");
    usuario_servicio.AgregarUsuario(usuario_form);
}
```

Of course the output from `System.out.println("*****" + request.getMethod() + "*****");` is `*****POST*****`

This is my `usuario_servicio.AgregarUsuario(usuario_form);` code:

```
public void AgregarUsuario(Usuario u) {
  Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  session.persist(u);
}
```

and I'm getting `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.logException Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported` error.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending csrf  token when you send a form via POST request. Add the next input to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```